# run toLowerCase() against all keys in object

Tags: javascript, object, tolower

How can I use javascript String `toLowerCase()` method against all keys in an object? I'm comparing the keys in Object 2 (wordBank) to the keys in Object 1 (taskObject)  to see if there is a match... I call:

`getAll(wordsObj["wordBank"]);`

Which calls:

```
getAll : function (taskObject) {

   for (obj in vocab) {
      for (key in vocab[obj]) {
         if (key in taskObject) {
            log(taskObject);
            log(key);
```

log(taskObject) outputs: `Object {Nǐ: "You", hǎo: "good", wǒ: "I", shì: "am"}`

log(key) outputs: `wǒ   hǎo   shì`

You can see here, that the `log(key)` is not outputting `Nǐ`, because the first letter is capitalized. How can I run `toLowerCase()` against all keys in Object 2 so that it returns all matches regardless of case?

**Object 1:** All entries are lower case

```
var vocab = 
{
    "Subjects" :
    {   
        'wǒ'    : ['I/Me',              path+sbj+'Wo_I.mp3'],
        'nǐ'    : ['You',               path+sbj+'Ni_You.mp3'],
    },
    "Adjectives" : 
    {
        'hǎo'   : ['Good',              path+adj+'Hao3_Good.mp3'],
        'shì'   : ['Am',            path+adj+'Shi4_Am.mp3'],
```

**Object 2 that I'm passing in to be compared:**

```
"wordBank" : //need to grab words from word bank... this is not needed...
{
    "Nǐ"    : "You",
    "hǎo"   : "good",
    "wǒ"    : "I",
    "shì"   : "am"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

why not:

`log(whatever.toLowerCase())`

Comment: I was just using logs there to show the output.  I am running other stuff in that if check that needs to know all matches of the key to the keys in object 2